# AWS Lambda finish before sending message to SQS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I'm running a "Node.JS" lambda on AWS that sends a message to SQS.
For some reason the **SQS callback function get execute only once every couple of calls**. It's looks like that the thread that running the lambda finish the run (because it's not a synchronous call to SQS and also can't return a Future) and therefore the lambda doesn't "stay alive" for the callback to get executed.

How can I solve this issue and have the lambda wait for the SQS callback to get execute?

Here is my lambda code:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {

// Set the region
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});

// Create an SQS service object
var sqs = new AWS.SQS({apiVersion: '2012-11-05'});
const SQS_QUEUE_URL = process.env.SQS_QUEUE_URL;

var params = {
    MessageGroupId: "cv",
    MessageDeduplicationId: key,
    MessageBody: "My Message",
    QueueUrl: SQS_QUEUE_URL
};

console.log(`Sending notification via SQS: ${SQS_QUEUE_URL}.`);
sqs.sendMessage(params, function(err, data) {   //<-- This function get called about one time every 4 lambda calls
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error", err);
        context.done('error', "ERROR Put SQS");  
    } else {
        console.log("Success", data.MessageId);
        context.done(null,'');  
    }
});

};
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should either stick to callback based approach, or to promise based one. I recommend you to use the latter:

```js
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {

  // Set the region
  AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});

  // Create an SQS service object
  var sqs = new AWS.SQS({apiVersion: '2012-11-05'});
  const SQS_QUEUE_URL = process.env.SQS_QUEUE_URL;

  var params = {
      MessageGroupId: "cv",
      MessageDeduplicationId: key,
      MessageBody: "My Message",
      QueueUrl: SQS_QUEUE_URL
  };

  console.log(`Sending notification via SQS: ${SQS_QUEUE_URL}.`);
  try {
      await sqs.sendMessage(params).promise(); // since your handler returns a promise, lambda will only resolve after sqs responded with either failure or success
  } catch (err) {
    // do something here
  }
};
```

P.S. Instantiating aws classes in the handler is not a good idea in lambda environment, since it increases the cold start time. It's better to move `new AWS.SQS(...)` action out of handler and `AWS.config.update()` too, since these actions will be executed on each call of the handler, but you really need them to be executed only once.

Comment: Thanks!, I thought that it doesn't support promise(). Working now :)